# Converting sql stored procedure to Linq/Lambda

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures, lambda

I have a stored procedure that displays a menu from table menus and then checks the user type to change the name of a menu item depending on the User type.

```
MenuID, 
    Case When @UserType <> 'E' and MenuName='Admin' then 'My Profile' When @UserType = 'A' and MenuName='Change Password' then 'Change Agent Password' else MenuName End As MenuName, 
    ParentID, 
    MenuLink,
    IconImagePath,
    MenuTarget 
from tblMenus          
Where IsDeleted=0 and 
      IsEnabled=1 and 
      MenuID in (Select MenuID From #MenuChild)                            
 Or MenuID In(SELECT ParentID FROM #MenuChild t CROSS APPLY dbo.FindRoot2(t.menuid))                            
 Or MenuID = 1  order by MenuOrder, MenuName
```

I have been working on converting the entire procedure to linq and it looks like this now.

```
 public List<tblMenu> getmainmenusclass()
        {  
             var UserInfo = GetUserInfo();
            UserType = UserInfo[0].UserTypeID;
            var menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList(); 
            if (UserType == "E")
                {
                    menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList();
                }

                if (UserType == "A")
                {
                    var agentDist = GetAgentDistribution();
                    Distribution = agentDist[0].AgtDistChannel;
                    if (Distribution == "P" || Distribution == "S")
                    {
                        menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.MenuCategory != "DGB").ToList();

                    }
                    if (Distribution == "G" || Distribution == "B")
                    {
                        menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.MenuCategory != "DPS").ToList();

                    }
                    if (Distribution == "W" || Distribution == "P")
                    {
                        menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.MenuCategory != "DGB" && x.MenuName != "NEW Quoting Tool").ToList();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    var notAllowedMenuCategories = new[] { "DPS", "DGB", "D" };
                    menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(x => x.IsDeleted == false && !notAllowedMenuCategories.Contains(x.MenuCategory)).ToList();

                        if (Distribution == "G")
                    {
                        var notAllowedMenuCategoriesForG = new[] { "DPS", "DGB", "D", "PB" };
                        menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(x => x.IsDeleted == false && !notAllowedMenuCategoriesForG.Contains(x.MenuCategory)).ToList();
                    }

                }
                if (MarketingGroup != "BWCU" && MarketingGroup != "''")
                    {
                        menus = DataAccess.Menus.FindByExp(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.MenuName != "NEW Quoting Tool").ToList();
                    }  
               return menus;
        }
```

I am not sure how to change that last bit so that it looks through the menu list and depending on the usertype changes the menu name from "Admin" to "My Profile".

Comment: You don't need to convert that to LINQ. If you're using Entity Framework 6+, you can hook that directly to a Stored Procedure. Before 6, there are other, messier ways to get information from a sproc.

Comment: I did that originally, lead decided that the stored procedure needed to be done away with.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Most of the time, that isn't the case and people don't realize you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you corectly, this is one way.

```
    menus = (from p in DataAccess.Menus 
               where p.usertype == 'A' 
              select new tblMenu 
             { //your properties except name
               Name="My Profile"
             }).Union(from p in DataAccess.Menus 
                  where p.usertype != "A" 
                  select p).ToList();
```

Change the usertype condition as you require. In this linq i'm taking all the elements from `DataAccess.Menus` and if the user type is A then i change one property as you requested. Then i'm joining that result with all the other elements that didn't match that `usertype`